# Why can't I build the app on my iOS device?

Tags: ios, windows, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I just got my Apple Developer account.
I got myself a MacBook Pro.

Those two were the only requirements I heard of to start developing iOS apps using Xamarin Visual Studio 2017.

I started off by connecting to my mac, it did connect successfully.
That's what it said at least.
Then I added a button to the form and here is where it all starts going downhill.

1. I can't find my device in the `device log`
2. When I try to build to my device it keeps saying

> Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS.

I looked into this issue and got told that I need to add my developer account in `Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts`
So that's what I did. And it still says the exact same thing.
What step did I miss here? Do I need to have Visual Studio running on the mac or what's going on here?

Here is a picture of the bundle singing
[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting the visual studio? Sorry for asking such a dumb question. I faced such a scenario once and after trying many scenarios, I simply restarted and it worked.

Comment: I did try it multiple times yeah

Comment: Have you tried creating an iOS project in Xcode and seeing if the developer provisioning in the Xcode project is working for your connected iOS device.

Comment: on the MacBook? The thing is I want to sit at my PC in Visual Studio and develop the apps.

Comment: @SushiHangover not sure if you got notified

Comment: @MarkDenom Yes, on the MacBook, TEST it... Open "Xcode" (not Visual Studio), create a new iOS project (Swift or ObjC-based), connect your iOS device and see if you can provision and deploy the app.

Comment: Also I used to ahev the iPhone connected to the PC and not the MAC is that a big issue? @SushiHangover

Comment: iPhone has to be connected to Mac, Xamarin is not a USB extender...

Comment: it does deploy the application from xCode to my iPhone @SushiHangover

Comment: @MarkDenom Now retry from VS4W (restarting VS first) and see if it picks up the provisioning profile

Comment: I did that, I now get an error saying Could not find any available provisioning profile for iOS. @SushiHangover

Comment: Did you add the device UDID to the devices list and create a provisioning profile in your Apple Developer account?